# SQL - Count( ) issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a charge/credit column:

```
Item | PriceVal | CostVal | CHARGE_CODE
1        5             3         CH
2        8             5         CH
1       -5            -3         CR
3        7             1         CH
4       15            10         CH
1        5             3         CH
```

I've got the query I need to get the NET price and cost, but I'm also interested in the NET charges. Right now I have:

```
SELECT Item, SUM(PriceVal), SUM(CostVal)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Item
```

How do I get another column with the value

```
COUNT(SUM(CHARGE_CODE=CH)-SUM(CHARGE_CODE=CR))
```

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

count() is going to count one for every value thats not null, so I don't think thats exactly what you want.  Take the count out and just take the

```
sum(case when charge_code = CH then costval else 0 end) 
- sum(case when charge_code = 'CR' then costval else 0 end)
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. That last part of my question wasn't very clear. I just wanted a count, so I modified yours just a little bit:
sum(case when charge_code = CH then 1 else 0 end) - sum(case when charge_code = 'CR' then 1 else 0 end)
Thanks!

Comment: well if you want a count, you could actually do it like this:
count(case when charge_code = 'CH' then 1 end)
count is going to count 1 when the value is not null and 0 when it is.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the dollar values entered as negatives in the table already, you can use the simple formula:

```
select
    Item,
    sum(PriceVal),
    sum(CostVal),
    sum(PriceVal-CostVal)
from Table
group by Item
```

I don't believe you should be subtracting the credit items as they're already negative.

If you really do want want the net **count** of transactions:

```
select
    Item,
    sum(PriceVal),
    sum(CostVal),
    sum(case when charge_code = 'CH' then 1 else 0 end) -
        sum(case when charge_code = 'CR' then -1 else 0 end)
from Table
group by Item
```

or, if there are only two charge codes, substitute:

```
sum(case when charge_code = 'CH' then 1 else -1 end)
```

for the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but you can count only certain rows like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(CHARGE_CODE=CH,1,NULL)) ...
```

And similarly sum certain values from certain rows like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(CHARGE_CODE=CH,PriceVal,0)) ...
```